# Create list with an object and its own value?

Tags: java, arrays, list, addition

How can you assign an object in a list, its own value?

Short and to the point.

Sorry, I will expand. I must've been far too vague.

Say I create a list named "age". I want to assign one of the objects within the list, "Joe", his age: "14".

So "Joe" -> "14", "Sam" -> "15", etc.?

Comment: It's _really_ not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Could you please provide a specific example of what you're looking for? What might the code look like?

Comment: Object always has its own value assigned to itself. Short and to the point ;)

Comment: Perhaps too short :) What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Expanded

Comment: Not perhaps, this question ***is*** too short and deficient of information and is not the best question we've seen here today. Voting to close soon if the necessary details aren't added soon.

Comment: Create a class to hold the name and the age and then create a List<T> of this class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Calm down there chap, I realize this. However, someone was still able to answer the question with my added details. Let's loosen up a bit ;-)

Comment: @GrayAdams:  yeah, someone answered after you got 4 completely unrelated answers. I'm not angry, but I hate to see folks wasting time due to someone being too lazy to ask a proper question, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Map you're after, not List.

Comment: I suspect this is the case, but I'm not positive.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I will promote you. I was way too lazy on asking this one. Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: Haha with the added info in the question it's clearly a `Map`, not a `List`. +1

Answer (score 1):

I you mean what you think you mean you should check out the set function:

```
list.set(index, object);
```

Comment: That's it's own index, check again. My bad.

Comment: Or perhaps `list.get(0).setAge` ?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, Yes depending on what you are trying to do. I responded before he edited his post so wasn't very clear what he wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want an object to create a list containing the object itself. So

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
list.add(this);
```

The keyword "this" always refers to the object whose method is executing (it's not available in static methods, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean. You want to reference the object itself within the object? 

For example:

```
list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

list.set(index, list);
// or
list.add(list);
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, or even if it would work. Try it out.